# How to use Dictionary Type Array in Php

Tags: c#, php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to use dictionary type array in php where i can have key and value is an array. 
i have written some code in C# but i dont know how to achieve this in php
laravel. anybody there knows the answer, please share with me. Thanks

Only this part:

```
      if (invoiceDictionary.ContainsKey(customerId))
      {
        List<Invoice> lstinvoices = invoiceDictionary[customerId]; 
        // get the  list by key 
        var discreteInvoces = lstinvoices.Where(x => x.invoiceNumber != 
        invoiceNumber).ToList(); // get all invoices execpt this
        invoiceDictionary[customerId] = discreteInvoces;
      }
      else
      {
        var discreteInvoces = getListInvoices().Where(x => x.invoiceNumber 
        != invoiceNumber).ToList(); //get all the invoice except this
        invoiceDictionary.Add(customerId, discreteInvoces);
        }
```

1. I have a class

   ```
   public class Invoice
   {
   public string invoiceNumber { get; set; }
   public string customerId { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. i have a list of Invoice object

   ```
    public List<Invoice> getListInvoices()
    {

       // just adding few invoices in the list 
       List<Invoice> lstinvoices = new List<Invoice>();
       Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
       invoice.customerId = "1231";
       invoice.invoiceNumber = "7003";
       lstinvoices.Add(invoice);

       invoice = new Invoice();
       invoice.customerId = "1231";
       invoice.invoiceNumber = "7002";
       lstinvoices.Add(invoice);
       return lstinvoices;
       // so now i have two invoices for customer 1231
    }
   ```

and i want to achieve this :

```
       public Dictionary<string, List<Invoice>> invoiceDictionary() //this 
       is main 
       {
        Dictionary<string, List<Invoice>> invoiceDictionary = new 
        Dictionary<string, List<Invoice>>();

        string customerId = "1231";
        string invoiceNumber = "7003";

        if (invoiceDictionary.ContainsKey(customerId))
        {

            List<Invoice> lstinvoices = invoiceDictionary[customerId]; 

            var discreteInvoces = lstinvoices.Where(x => x.invoiceNumber != invoiceNumber).ToList(); // get all invoices execpt this
            invoiceDictionary[customerId] = discreteInvoces;
        }
        else
        {
            var discreteInvoces = getListInvoices().Where(x => x.invoiceNumber != invoiceNumber).ToList(); //get all the invoice except this
            invoiceDictionary.Add(customerId, discreteInvoces);
        }
        return invoiceDictionary;
    }
```